# unable to set focus on controls inside tab control in wpf

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am trying to set focus on my user control using attached property that is exposing a dependency property "IsFocus" in my user control and binding it to a property in my Window. Although this works fine for all controls in the window and the first tab, i am not able to set focus on controls which is on other tabs. I even got the tab in focus on which my control is and then tried to get the focus but in vain. What am i missing here? Or is that wpf tab does not allow focus of controls using attached property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by adding "AdornerDecorator" tag just below the "tabitem" tag and then add all controls inside the "AdornerDecorator" tag.

Answer (score 0):

try this...if you want to select the textBox1 in tabcontrol..

```
tabcontrol.IsSelected=true;
PutFocusOnControl(textBox1);
```

and define the method...

```
 private void PutFocusOnControl(Control element)
        {
            if (element != null)
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Input,
                    (System.Threading.ThreadStart)delegate
                    {
                        element.Focus();
                    });
        }
```